# Why the ultimate base class of all classes in the .NET Framework called System.Object?

Tags: .net

Why the ultimate base class of all classes in the .NET Framework called System.Object? It must be called System.Class or something because this is class not the class instance (object).

Comment: Maybe object as in object-oriented programming...

Comment: I've answered your question as well as I could understand it, but it would help if you'd put more effort into explaining yourself clearly. In the process of writing a good question, you may well have discovered the answer. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for hints about writing a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called `System.Object` because every object *is an object*. For example, an instance of `String` is an `Object` - but a `String` isn't a class, is it? The string *class* is a class, but that's a different matter.

There's `System.Type` to represent types, so an instance of `System.Type` knows what properties, methods etc the type has. So you can use something like:

```
Type stringType = typeof(string);
// Find out all the members of System.String using stringType...
```

But it wouldn't be appropriate to be able to call `GetProperties`, `GetMethods` etc on a string itself - because a string is just a sequence of characters.